# skip first row from file on ftp server in informatica

Tags: ftp, informatica

There is a file on ftp server whose data has to be loaded to a target table.

Example :

```
id,name,address
1,abc,aaa
2,xyz,bbb
```

Now the requirement is that we have to skip the column names (i.e. the first row) . How to do it in informatica. I have used ftp connection to get the data but don't have idea how to skip the columns names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source file definition set the option "Number of initial rows to skip" to 1

You will find in the Advanced section of Table tab. Make sure you do the same change in session as well.